# Force "Scaling performed by Application" for all apps

Tags: windows-10, dpi, high-dpi

Windows automatically scales DPI-unaware apps making them blurry. I am able to override this per-program in the program compatibility properties (resulting in the program being smaller, but not blurry):

[image: High DPI scaling override dialog]

I would like this to be the default for all programs I run. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `__COMPAT_LAYER` environment variable stores the compatibility flags. Among that is `HighDpiAware` so you can set it with the below command

```
setx __COMPAT_LAYER HighDpiAware /M
```

See also [Global DPI Scaling Disable for Win8.1 for all files/users](https://www.eightforums.com/threads/global-dpi-scaling-disable-for-win8-1-for-all-files-users.42452/?__cf_chl_jschl_tk__=f518009a47cdb4529615cce36a8da2f1e924ee7a-1612598223-0-Aas568hk1opkaVKfRlOeSJ1D2jPOpglKbMXrrLpwq-aTBhByeGrEKmooeJ5BpLjf20QnxmxWF9bYB4nPOSS27e5gIx1HJm_QXroezrkMlmfXEDcn4mDng_Git72DESQkO-SLB4AJ08fFOW_HMbkvGGDnoD2FH_xs2RTJ6Jh4aeyz0UKmsUXQye5byfwoGoTWgeI6nkmWRT2HqNcsJRJBb_nSwPMZ1JPgCtgEbi_5HnEAyUzXB2TKnAqXD5P2fA2JVwa-5Zy710mI_2-XhfD9gglvrdqNtZU5MrzjGV6x25ulWp4MOwOlF3UTipWEFca-ltgput4BKo9uPem-mZJFWQvDBjXMmn9b-OJ9Qu__X9WjyAsaG5HZfsgw5pHcz4kp2RlPdybWdp6e3jloyQ4WO7c)